# Need help on this integration question that requires trig substitution

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

$\int8/({4x^2+1})^2$ . I need help integration this question and need to use trig substituion to do so. I know there is another way but i have to use trig sub and specifically make *2x=tan(x)* or similar i think.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By using the change of variable $2x=\tan u$, $2dx=(\tan^2 u+1)\:du$ , one gets
$$
\int \frac{dx}{(4x^2+1)^2}=\frac12\int \frac{(\tan^2 u+1)}{(\tan^2 u+1)^2}\:du=\frac12\int \cos^2u \:du=\frac14\int (1+\cos(2u)) \:du.
$$

Comment: @electro7912 It is the same thing, we have $dx=1/2(\sec^2(u))du=1/2(\tan^2 u+1)du$.

Comment: yes i've gotten to that part. But now im stuck on replacing back 2x. My final answer is 2arctan(2x)+2sin(x)cos(x). Can;t seem to find a way to get rid of that 2sin(x)cos(x) which the answer said should give me 4x/(4x^2+1)

Comment: the book says the answer should be 2arctan(2x)+4x/(4x^2+1). Sorry for the format. Not yet familiar with this website

Comment: @electro7912 You may write $2\sin u \cos u=\frac{2\sin u \cos u}{\cos^2u+\sin^2u}=\frac{2\tan u }{1+\tan^2u}$ thus with $2x=\tan u$ one gets $2\sin u \cos u=\frac{4x }{1+4x^2}$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint, to finish**

Let us begin by $t=2x$,

$$\int \frac{8}{(4x^2+1)^2}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{4}{(1+t^2)^2}dt =4J$$

$$J=\int\frac{1+t^2-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

$$=\arctan(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\int t\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

by parts...